# Just upgraded to macOS Catalina, how do I fix my Firefox Nightly appearance (red background, blurry text)?

Tags: macos, firefox, macos-catalina

I just upgraded my MacBook Pro to macOS Catalina, and everything seems to be working fine except for my Firefox Nightly, `Version: 71.0a1 (2019-10-08) (64-bit)`. It now looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This seems likely to be a bug in the Firefox nightlies. This is the kind of thing you have to expect if you're running nightlies of a project. Consider tracking down the bug in the Firefox codebase and submitting a fix to Firefox. You could run the released version of Firefox until your fix lands in the nightlies. Or rather, run your own build with your fix until then.

Comment: @Spiff The Developer Edition is not a nightly build and my standard FF was doing exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by going to `Help` -> `Troubleshooting Information` -> `Refresh Nightly...`

Comment: This worked for me too. Thank you, I was beginning to panic.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Turned out to be linked to WebRender.

To disable it:

- open `about:config`
- set `gfx.webrender.enabled` and `gfx.webrender.all` to `false`
- restart Firefox

Comment: I marked my own answer as the solution, because it's what worked for me, but this is probably the better solution.